# is it possible to skip null column for alias stattement

Tags: sql, alias

really need ur help on this matter... i tried to generate report for work description of construction company. however, i've faced a problem to skip null column in order to generate the report.
after doing research on google i came out with alias but still i couldn't skip null columns

Stored in database:

```
CompNo|CodeA|CodeB|CodeC|CodeD|CodeE|CodeF|CodeG|CodeH|CodeI|CodeJ|CodeK|
A10001|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     | W09 |     |
A10003| W01 | W02 |     | W04 |     |     |     | W07 | W08 |     | W10 |
A10002| W01 | W02 | W03 | W04 |     |     |     | W07 | W08 | W09 | W10 |
```

Expected output in report:

```
A10001  W09                                                                   
A10003  W01 W02 W04 W07 W08 W10               
A10002  W01 W02 W03 W04 W07 W08 W09 W10
```

Report currently generated:

```
A10001                                            W09                                                                    
A10003  W01 W02     W04                   W07 W08               W10                                                                            
A10002  W01 W02 W03 W04                   W07 W08 W09           W10
```

Comment: SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL?????

Comment: What is your current query ? And which DBMS you are using ?

Comment: If you actually want to have the fields still be discrete fields, you'll have to do backflips to get this to work in pure SQL.  You're trying to tell the query engine that `CodeJ` needs to be in the same columns as `CodeA`... but only sometimes.  This is a display problem, not a database problem.  It should be resolved in your application.  That said, the most straightforward way to force this is to happen is to just concatenate all your fields together.  The problem is that you only get 2 fields that way: CompNo, and everything else.

Comment: am using SQL Server 2005. I am using select alias for current query... yeap Bacon Bits this is about report display... i am trying to eliminate the blank columns inside in order to make the report more proper

Answer (score 0):

below was the code that i've already used... it looks fine... but i need to eliminate the empty column inside of *`tblCompanyWrkDesc`* (table name) if the data not available.

```
select tblCompany.compno, tblCompany.CompName, tblcompany.CompAdd, tblCompany.CompTel, tblCompany.CompFax, tblCompany.CompEmail, 
tblCompany.CntcPerName, tblCompany.CntcPerTel, tblCompany.RegNo, 
tblCompany.RocRob, tblCompany.Cidb, tblCompany.Spkk, tblCompany.Ppk, tblCompany.Status, tblCompany.Others,



Substring(tblCompany.RegDate,7,2) + '/' + Substring(tblCompany.RegDate,5,2) + '/' + Substring(tblCompany.RegDate,1,4) as Rd, 
Substring(tblCompany.VldtStart,7,2) + '/' + Substring(tblCompany.VldtStart,5,2) + '/' + Substring(tblCompany.VldtStart,1,4) as Fd, 
Substring(tblCompany.VldtEnd,7,2) + '/' + Substring(tblCompany.VldtEnd,5,2) + '/' + Substring(tblCompany.VldtEnd,1,4) as Ld, 

tblCompanyWrkDesc.Compno, tblCompanyWrkDesc.CodeA+' '+tblCompanyWrkDesc.CodeB+' '+tblCompanyWrkDesc.CodeC+' '+tblCompanyWrkDesc.CodeD+' '+tblCompanyWrkDesc.CodeE+' '+tblCompanyWrkDesc.CodeF+' '+tblCompanyWrkDesc.CodeG+' '+tblCompanyWrkDesc.CodeH+' '+tblCompanyWrkDesc.CodeI+' 
'+tblCompanyWrkDesc.CodeJ+' '+tblCompanyWrkDesc.CodeK+' '+tblCompanyWrkDesc.CodeL+' '+tblCompanyWrkDesc.CodeM+' '+tblCompanyWrkDesc.CodeN+' 
'+tblCompanyWrkDesc.CodeO+' '+tblCompanyWrkDesc.CodeP+' '+tblCompanyWrkDesc.CodeQ+' '+tblCompanyWrkDesc.CodeR+' '+tblCompanyWrkDesc.CodeS+' 
'+tblCompanyWrkDesc.CodeT+' '+tblCompanyWrkDesc.CodeU+' '+tblCompanyWrkDesc.CodeV+' '+tblCompanyWrkDesc.CodeW+' '+tblCompanyWrkDesc.CodeX as WorkDesc, 
tblCompanyWrkDesc.CodeOthers, tblCompanyWrkDesc.Other

from tblCompany, tblCompanyWrkDesc

WHERE tblCompanyWrkDesc.Compno = tblCompany.compno
ORDER BY tblCompany.RefNo
```

Comment: If this isn't an answer (it doesn't appear to be), it shouldn't be posted *as* an answer. It looks like you're trying to show your code in which case you should *edit* your *question* to add the code.

Comment: sorry... huhu im trying to share on what i already have...
this is my first time on using this website on looking the solutions..